# SQL Query in Generalization

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms, erd

Relational Schema:

```
Table comics(Generalization):
    comic_name: varchar(Primary Key)
    Created: boolean(Default = false)
    Group_name: varchar(55), (Not Null)
    Type: varchar(55), (Not Null)

Table Unreleased_comics(Specialization):
    comic_Name: Foreign Key(comics, comic_name)

Table Released_comics(Specialization):
    comic_Name: Foreign Key(comics, comic_name)
    Release_Date: date (Not Null)
```

Relation in ER: Comics isA Unreleased_Comics and Released_Comics

What should be the SQL Query for listing all the comics that were released before 2001? (MySQL)

Comment: Which field contains the `album name`?

Comment: The field *Created* doesn't seem to have any use.  Do you know what it is?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it should be comics @wallyk

Comment: Created field is for status that is the comic is created yet or not @wallyk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a simple `INNER JOIN` the more colibated part can be to cholse zhe right date,
but as you only want the year, is still simple

```
SELECT 
    c.comic_name, c.Created, c.Group_name, c.Type, r.Release_Date
FROM
    comics crossINNER
        JOIN
    Released_comics r ON c.comic_name = r.comic_name
WHERE
    YEAR(r.Release_Date) < 2001
```

Comment: the r is actually Released_Comics right?, and c is Comics